# VBA - Alternatives to Using Shell32.dll

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a VBA script that will take an email address, then open it in a new window. The trick is I'll need to get it to run without using Shell32.dll.

Based on the code, below, is there any other way to rewrite the following?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long

Public Sub OpenUrl()

Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
Dim sTemp As String
Dim sURL As String

If olItem.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
    sTemp = olItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    sTemp = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
End If

sURL = "https://afakeurl.com/" + sTemp

Dim lSuccess As Long


lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", sURL)

End Sub
```

Comment: Use VB's `Shell` function... which is basically a wrapper around the Win32 API function.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont wanna use it? Can you explain it more?
You can use the VBA Shell:

```
Shell "cmd.exe"
```

One alternative way is to use

```
set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.run "Your thing"
```

This uses the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
But I think behind the scene it will use the Shell32.dll anyway

Comment: Our code review team would prefer not to have the script use ShellExecute to open to link, but I'm not sure if that is possible. I'm only a novice at VBA

Comment: Well I wrote you to alternative ways without using directly the WINAPI